# Distance between two geopints

Tags: android, distance, latitude-longitude

Following two line calculate the lat and lng

```
double geoLat = location.getLatitude(); //  37.422006
double geoLng = location.getLongitude(); //   -122.084095
```

In a loop i calculate the distance array between geo points.  latitude[i] and longitude[i] comes as json response from google map api

```
distance[i]=GetLatAndLng.gps2m(geoLat, geoLng,latitude[i] ,longitude[i]);
```

This is gps2m method.

```
public static double gps2m(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
 double l1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double l2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double g1 = Math.toRadians(lng1);
    double g2 = Math.toRadians(lng2);

    double dist = Math.acos(Math.sin(l1) * Math.sin(l2) + Math.cos(l1) * Math.cos(l2) * Math.cos(g1 - g2));
    if(dist < 0) {
        dist = dist + Math.PI;
    }
    return Math.round(dist * 6378100);//in meters

}
}
```

In the distance array i m getting value like 1.1967617E7 
I want distance in meters

What is going wrong and how to get distance in meters.

Help!!

Comment: What's wrong with 1.1967617E7 as a value for the number of meters?

Comment: it is too large.. even i use distanceBetween method and got same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Location class. You can calculate the distance in two ways:

```
location.distanceTo(anotherLocation);
```

or

```
Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results);
```

Take a look at the [Location documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) for more details.

Comment: The values you get from location.getLatitude();

Comment: but i m getting too large value appx. 11958 KM and this is a program of finding nearby resturants.lol both method giving the same results

Comment: Then you should think about your input parameters... which values do they have?

Comment: hey you are right input parameters was wrong thank you so much.

Comment: What is the `float[] results` parameter supposed to be?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you can see the exact definition here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code:

```
int EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371;
double lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,lat1Rad,lat2Rad,deltaLonRad,dist,nDist;
lat1 = latitude of location 1

lon1 = longitude of location 1

lat2 = latitude of location 2

lon2 = longitude of location 2

lat1Rad = Math.toRadians(lat1);

lat2Rad = Math.toRadians(lat2);

deltaLonRad = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

dist = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1Rad) * Math.sin(lat2Rad) + Math.cos(lat1Rad) * Math.cos(lat2Rad) * Math.cos(deltaLonRad)) * EARTH_RADIUS_KM;

nDist = Math.round(dist*0.62);

String strDistance = Double.toString(nDist)+" Miles";
```

The dist you get is in double and KM, you might want to round up the value that you're getting, do this by using `Math.round(dist*0.62);`

*0.62 is to convert KM into miles.

Comment: +1 thanks your method gives accurate results for short distance helpful!!